# Estimating the difference between two heating circuits

Tags: resistance, heat

Two circuits are built using a conductive paste composed of conductive powder in a resin binder. The goal is for the circuits to produce heat through Joule heating.

Circuit A uses only one type of conductive powder in the conductive paste.

Circuit B uses a mixture of two different types of conductive powder - one is the same as the powder in circuit A, and the other is a lower resistance powder. The lower resistance powder has half the resistance of the higher-resistance powder. The ratio of the two different conductive powders is 75% high-resistance powder, to 25% lower-resistance powder. The powders are mixed randomly.

Can I calculate the heat produced by circuit B as follows?

Circuit B's heat = (Circuit A's heat * 0.75) + ((Circuit A's heat * 0.25) * 0.5)

When the high resistance powder in circuit B is mixed with the low resistance powder, will the high resistance powder still produce heat through Joule heating to the same extent, or will the presence of the low-resistance powder reduce the heat produced by the high-resistance powder in some way?

Comment: Can you draw a diagram with the tool? You can draw circuit A and B as resistive loads

Comment: Your calculation for Circuit B's heat gives you a result that is lower than Circuit A's heat. But a lower resistance for Circuit B would result in higher current flow - leading to *more* heat, not less.

Comment: The description of Joule heating assumes a constant current, so a lower resistance will lead to proportionally lower power dissipation.